# RandomForestRegressor predict values of 2D array

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have irradiated some radiochromic film at different doses and scanned them in as a Tiff, 48 bit RGB to use as a calibration. My dataset comprises of three columns representing the colour channels (X) and the corresponding dose (y). The input data is of the form

[image]

I have used the sklearn RandomForestRegressor to train and test successfully. When I use the following (net optical density RGB values)

```
X = df[['RedDensity', 'GreenDensity', 'BlueDensity']].values
y = df['Dose'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

regressor.predict(np.array([0.349, 0.296, 0.107]).reshape(1, 3))
```

I get a predicted value for the dose. My question is how do I predict the values of a test image of (m x n x 3)? I could scan across the test image and read the RGB value of each element but is there a more elegant way?
Thanks
James

Comment: can you add more details to the question? Inputs sample for training and test data, and elaborate on the expected output

Comment: Just hit the entire image as the parameter: regressor.predict(img). No need to iterate through each record.

Comment: I tried sending it the image but get the error 'Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.' The test image is (10,10,3).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070437/valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expected-2

Comment: Problem is I want to pass it the image of raw values and get an image of dose values back. I have got round it by iteratively slicing a column, passing it to the regressor and creating a new array slice by slice.